# HTTPS in EE6/Servlet Container

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

Is there a way to retrieve the https port of the EE6/Servlet Container in a standard way?
If not maybe a method to convert an URL in a standard way to use https?

I know I could use a security constraint in web.xml, but the behavior is not configurable at runtime as far as I know.

Maybe it is a bad idea to allow the user or admin to choose whether to use https or not?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to get using the standard API. If it is TomCat Server, I have seen some workarounds by parsing server.xml.

Comment: Do you think that it is bad practice to allow non https connections anyway? I mean, this is just for the backend. Front end will be setup as the customer needs it.

Comment: No. I don't think it's bad idea at all. For some reason EE 6 doesn't expose it. Check out EE 7, I guess it's there but I haven't played with it.